# Regex to match a word with + (plus) signs

Tags: c#, regex

I've spent some time, but still have to solution. I need regular expression that is able to match a words with signs in it (like c++) in string.

I've used `/\bword\b/`, for "usual" words, it works OK. But as soon as I try `/\bC\+\+\b/` it just does not work. It some how works wrong with a plus signs in it.

I need a regex to detect if input string contains c++ word in it. Input like,

```
"c++ developer"
"using c++ language"
```

etc.

ps. Using C#, .Net Regex.Match function.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`+` is a special character so you need to escape it

```
\bC\+\+(?!\w)
```

Note that we can't use `\b` because `+` is not a word-character.

Comment: Hi Kenny, I'm using it. It was not displayed in view. I've corrected a question. Does not work like that.

Comment: Visual Studio won't compile when I try escaping the plus-sign.

Comment: @WEFX Add an `@` before the double-quote: `@"\bC\+\+(?!\w)"`

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't with the plus character, that you've escaped correctly, but the `\b` sequence. It indicates a word boundary, which is a point between a word character (alphanumeric) and something else. Plus isn't a word character, so for `\b` to match, there would need to be a word character directly after the last plus sign.

`\bC\+\+\b` matches "Test C++Test" but not "Test C++ Test" for example. Try something like `\bC\+\+\s` if you expect there to be a whitespace after the last plus sign.

Comment: Specifically `\b` matches between a `\w` and a `\W` (or visa versa).

Comment: thank you for great answer!

\bC\+\+\s, works great, but it also matches space after last + sign, it is not big issue, but anyway a little unexpected.

Comment: @alexander You can make the space a lookahead to avoid including it in the match: `\bC\+\+(?=\s)`.

Answer (score 4):

Plus sign have special meaning so you will have to escape it with `\`. The same rule applies to these characters: `\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #,` and white space

UPDATE: the problem was with `\b` sequence

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match a `c++` between non-word chars (chars other than letters, digits and underscores) you may use

```
\bc\+\+\B
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bcpyfG/1) where `\b` is a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and `\B` matches all positions that are not word boundary positions.

C# syntax:

```
var pattern = @"\bc\+\+\B";
```

You must remember that `\b` / `\B` are context dependent: `\b` matches between the start/end of string and the adjoining word char or between a word and a non-word chars, while `\B` matches between the start/end of string and the adjoining *non-*word char or between two word or two non-word chars.

**If you build the pattern dynamically, it is hard to rely on word boundary `\b` pattern.**

Use [**adaptive dynamic wod boundaries**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970), `(?!\B\w)` and `(?<!\w\B)` lookarounds instead, they will always match a word not immediately preceded/followed with a word char if the word starts/ends with a word char:

```
var pattern = $@"(?!\B\w){Regex.Escape(word)}(?<!\w\B)";
```

If the word boundaries you want to match are whitespace boundaries (i.e. the match is expected only between whitespaces), use

```
var pattern = $@"(?<!\S){Regex.Escape(word)}(?!\S)";
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, your problem isn't the `+` sign you've escaped correctly but the `\b` that is a zero-lenght char that match word boundary that takes place between word `\w` and non-word `\W` char.

There is also another mistake in your regex, you want to match char `C` (uppercase) with `c++` (lowercase).To do so you have to change your regex to `/\bc\+\+/` or use the `i` modifier to match case insensitive : `/\bc\+\+/i`