# How can I validate that a phone number has a + in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

```
$().ready(function() {
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit


    $.validator.addMethod("custom_number", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value === "NA" ||
        value.match(/^[0-9,\-]+$/);
}, "Please enter a valid number, or 'NA'");


$("#getForm").validate({
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        company: "required",
        email: {required: true, email: true},
        number: {required: true, number: true,custom_number: true},
        textarea: "required",
        partners: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter name",
        company: "Please enter your company name",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        number: "Please enter a valid phone number",
        textarea: "Please enter your requirements",
        partners: "Partners can't be blank"
    }
});
```

Could any one tell me in above coding.... 
How to add + symbol to be validated in phone number

Comment: `/^\+[0-9,\-]+$/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match a word with + (plus) signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641985/regex-to-match-a-word-with-plus-signs)

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form >
  Number <input type="text" name="number" pattern="^[+]([0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$" title="number should start with + symbol" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

try this, good luck..

Comment: i have updated the code. sry for the mistake.. its really working now.. try it.. sorry for my small mistake.. try it good luck